# Webclient Error Handling - Spring Webflux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to throw my custom exceptions with the following conditions:

1. If I am getting proper error response in json format, I want to deserialize it and throw my exception named **CommonException** inside **onStatus()**
2. If I am receiving an HTML content as part of response or deserialization didnt happen successfully then I want to throw **GenericException** which I am creating inside **onErrorMap()**
3. While throwing a GenericException, I want to pass the same HttpStatus code to upstream which I am getting from downstream response.

   ```
    IdVerificationResponse idVerificationResponse = client.get()
    .uri(idVerificationUrl)
    .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpEntity.getHeaders()))
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response ->
        //Throw this one only if deserialization of error response to IdVerificationErrorResponse class happens successfully

        response.bodyToMono(IdVerificationErrorResponse.class)
            .flatMap(error -> Mono.error(CommonException.builder().message(error.getCustomMessage()).build()))
    )
    .bodyToMono(IdVerificationResponse.class)
    .onErrorMap(error -> {
        //Come over here only if there is an error in deserialization in onStatus()

        //How to get the HttpStatus we are getting as part of error response from the downstream
        HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
        ApiErrorDetails errorDetailsObj = ApiErrorDetails.builder().errorCode(httpStatus.name()).errorDescription("Error related to HTML")
              .errorDetails("Error related to HTML").build();
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = ErrorDetails.builder().errors(errorDetailsObj).build();
        return GenericException.builder().errorDetails(errorDetails).httpStatus(httpStatus).build();
    }).block();
   ```

Currently onErrorMap() is getting called everytime and overriding the exception I am throwing inside onStatus()

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution

```
IdVerificationResponse idVerificationResponse = client.get()
    .uri(processCheckUrl)
    .headers(headers -> headers.addAll(httpEntity.getHeaders()))
    .retrieve()
    .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, response -> {
            HttpStatus errorCode = response.statusCode();
            return response.bodyToMono(IdVerificationErrorResponse.class)
                .onErrorMap(error -> new Exception("Throw your generic exception over here if there is any error in deserialization"))
                .flatMap(error -> Mono.error(new Exception("Throw your custom exception over here after successful deserialization")));
        })
    .bodyToMono(IdVerificationResponse.class).block();
```

Comment: Are you using the block only for this example purpose? If not then it will be a bad practice and you should return the Mono instead of blocking it.

Comment: @PratikSherke Yeah its only for the example purpose.